# change images every 5 seconds - but images from server

Tags: jquery, python, html, django

i am trying to change the users in every seven seconds.  for this, i need to load all information of user from server. how can i do this using javascript? what is the efficient way?

what i thought about is, i send every seven seconds an http request to server asking for user data with ajax. it is efficient way of doing this?

http://doni.sites.djangoeurope.com/ this is my site and in bottom part you see 5 users. i want them to change to another user in every seven seconds.

please help me. i am using serverside django,

Comment: You've got a solution, why not try it? Can you think of a reason to not do it the way you said? No? Then do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple logic would be to use `setInterval` function. Lets us assume that I have to change the background of a webpage after every 5 seconds. You could use the below code to achieve this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function changebackground() {
            var colors = ["#0099cc","#c0c0c0","#587b2e",
"#990000","#000000","#1C8200","#987baa","#464646",
"#AA8971","#1987FC","#99081E"];

            setInterval(function() {
                var bodybgarrayno = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
                var selectedcolor = colors[bodybgarrayno];
                document.body.style.background = selectedcolor;
            }, 3000);
        }
        </script>
```

You could replicate the above functionality for your requirements.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/refhat/gJWFR/1/)**

Comment: @doniyor: glad that it helped you. I have added a DEMO too. make sure you check that also.

Answer (score 2):

the most efficient way is to use [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) , you should document on them.

Only thing is they are not always [suppoerted from browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=websockets)

You can also do somenthing like:

```
setInterval(function(){
//launch my ajax every 5 seconds
},5000);
```

but it do not reccomend you this

Comment: you dont recommend me ajax? can you give some reason?

Comment: no i do not reccomen you setInterval() :) cause this charges a lot the browser

Comment: @doniyor so go for cross-browser solution, setInterval() and you launch it everywhen you want